# HP Pavilion M7 laptop - keyboard not working

Tags: 14.04, usb, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

It is and old I7 laptop with a Canadian multilingual keyboard (I hate the manufactures which try to be politically correct) which works OK with Windows and an old openSUSE 13.1.

I tried Kubuntu 14.04, 16.04, 18.04, 20.04, Mint 19.3 & openSUSE Tumbleweed and the result is the same: the laptop's keyboard does not work after installation. An USB keyboard works just fine and it is the only way I can stop the laptop's keyboard to repeat very fast the very key I touch. After the first use of the USB keyboard the laptop's keyboard goes mute.

During the "Try Ubuntu" and "Install Ubuntu" procedures the laptop keyboard works just fine but after installation it goes mad. Does anybody know what keyboard options are passed to the installation image?

Thanks,

Cristian

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I gave up trying and went back to the last working installation, open SUSE 13.1, where the laptop's keyboard works (and worked before). Seems that this laptop is condemned to use it until it dies. Will never ever buy anything made by HP.